# React Native Confirmation Modal - With Just One Liner Code

Tags: javascript, react-native, modal-dialog

In my React Native application,  I frequently need some confirmation popups.
I want to show my popups in an elegant way with my own component styles so I use Modals instead of Alert command.

Is there any way to code simply with one line like below :

```
function myCallerFunction() { 

  const lv_conf_result = showConfirmPopup("Please confirm");

  if (lv_conf_result)
  {
     // ... do something
  }

}
```

I mean is there anyway in "showConfirmPopup" function above , I can show my own Modal and get which button pressed without leaving caller function myCallerFunction and the local state of this function ?

Thank you

Comment: Could you provide an example of these "new functions" you make?

Comment: Hi @EmilKarlsson I've written question again,  sorry I think I couldn't explain what I need clearly

Comment: A popup will wait for a user to interact with it. A function will carry on immediately. You probably need to use async-await if you want to use the result of a button press within the function that creates (among other things) the button you are expecting to get pressed. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await

Answer (score 0):

You could use [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) like this:

```
async function myCallerFunction() { 

  const lv_conf_result = await showConfirmPopup("Please confirm");

  if (lv_conf_result)
  {
     // ... do something
  }

}
```

Then in your function `showConfirmPopup`:

```
async function showConfirmPopup(message) {
  const promise = new Promise();

  // codes to display your dialog
  ...

  // inside 'confirm' button press event handler
  ...
  promise.resolve(value);
  ...


  // inside 'cancel' button press event handler
  ...
  promise.reject();
  ...
  

  return promise;
}
```